# Missing textures in linked files using Botaniq/Graswald Addons

Tags: texturing, add-on, blend-files, linked-data

I am working on a pretty massive file, therefore I have broken it down into different files, all linked into one main file.

I am using the Botaniq and Graswald addons in most of these linked files.

I have saved the main file which has all the linked data and tried to open it on another machine, only to find the dreaded pink textures of missing files.

Everything else is fine, since I have a dedicated Texture folder. But anything created with the addons just doesn't show up and I cannot for the life of me figure out where Graswald and Botaniq save their texture data.

Comment: Likely something set in an addon pref in blender user prefs. Otherwise addon should have their own docs of some kind, but I have never heard of these addons.

Comment: If memory serves you have buttons in the panels of these addons that will look for broken data links. Does this help ?

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for the input! Yes, they do. The problem is that is not working, since i am transferring the file on to another machine. So it cannot find the missing files :/ I was wondering if there was a way to get a folder where all the textures from the addons could be stored/found.